# incron and files with round brackets

Tags: incron

I have installed incron and the following incrontab.

```
/inputdir IN_ALL_EVENTS /root/jobs/monitor $@ $% $#
```

Here is the monitor script that is called on all events.

```
!/bin/bash
#
LOG=/var/log/incron.log
TS="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"

# $1 - monitored dir
# $2 - action
# $3 - file in action
#
echo -e "${TS}  ${1} : ${2} : ${3}" >> ${LOG}
```

As soon as I copy a file to /inputdir I get a log entry in incron.log.
This is the expected behavior.

But if I copy a file with round brackets e.g. test(1).pdf nothing happens.
Altough there is an entry in journald monitor script is not called and I dont have an entry in my incron.log.

I think this is an error.
Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the code, and the way incron works is:

1. Escape spaces and backslashes in the filename ([`IncronTabEntry::GetSafePath`](https://github.com/ar-/incron/blob/ncron-0.5.12/incrontab.cpp#L161-L179)
2. Substitute the directory name, filename, etc. in the command line
3. Run the processed command line using either `/bin/sh -c` (using `system()` for [the root user](https://github.com/ar-/incron/blob/ncron-0.5.12/usertable.cpp#L474)) or `/bin/bash -c` ([for normal users - `UserTable::RunAsUser`](https://github.com/ar-/incron/blob/master/usertable.cpp#L611))

In neither case is `(` or `)` safe to pass unescaped. (And not just these, but other special characters like `;`, `*`, `[`/`]`, `&&`, `$( ... )`, etc.) This is a command injection vulnerability waiting to be exploited. See, e.g., [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448449/70524) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/70524) for the pitfalls in embedding filenames directly into shell command strings. Arch Linux has [a patch](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/incron/-/blob/main/0001-GetSafePath.patch) expanding the set of characters that are escaped which will solve your particular problem since it includes `(` and `)`, but still misses out on `*`, `;`, `|`, etc.

You can work around this somewhat by trying to quote the command line in the `incrontab`:

```
/inputdir IN_ALL_EVENTS /root/jobs/monitor '$@' $% '$#'
```

But this will still fail for filenames with `'` in them. All you can really do is file a bug report asking for more escaping, or ask them to use `execve` and family to run the command directly instead of using `system()` or running `/bin/bash -c '...'`. The problem then is that they will have to parse the command line differently, splitting it into words, and implement an escaping mechanism, etc.